# Count the number of accesses made to a file

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine what process has a file open in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/97844/how-can-i-determine-what-process-has-a-file-open-in-linux)

Can I run a script/use a tool that monitors a file and counts the number of access that are made to it (both read and write). I am running multiple threads and trying to record the number of reads/writes that are made to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `strace` command. Which will display or record system calls from process.  For example, this will record the `open`, `read`, and `write` systems calls made by the command `cat /etc/passwd` to the file /tmp/tracelog

```
strace -o /tmp/tracelog -f -e trace=open,read,write cat /etc/passwd
```