# "screen is terminating" for non-root

Tags: linux, centos, gnu-screen, centos-7

When I try to run screen as a non-root user I get:

```
screen

[screen is terminating]
```

immediately, though it works fine for root

```
ls -alh /usr/bin/screen
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root screen 465K Jun  9 20:30 /usr/bin/screen
```

When googling around I noticed a mention of /etc/fstab, here is mine:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md1        /       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
/dev/md2        /home   ext4    defaults        1       2
/dev/sda3       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
/dev/sdb3       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults                0       0
tmpfs           /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  defaults        0       0
```

This on a freshly installed centos 7 on a dedicated server accessed through ssh ( TTY is pts )

Any help would be appreciated.

```
screen -ls    
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-user.

ls -la /var/run/screen/S-user
total 0
drwx------ 2 user user 40 Jul 10 18:23 .
drwxrwxr-t 4 root     screen   80 Jul 10 17:59 ..
```

Comment: Run `screen -ls`; it should give a directory name in the first line. Then, run `ls -la <above directory name>` and put the output in your question.

Comment: Ok, added it to the question.

Comment: Hmmmm...I expected to see a permissions problem there, but it looks fine.

Comment: I am trying to get a VM of CentOS 7 going to see if it also has this problem, but I might not get it done til tomorrow...

Comment: Is there a reason you need CentOS 7? It seems that perhaps it is related to the fact that CentOS 7 was *just* released. Perhaps you could use CentOS 6 for a few more weeks?

Comment: I do not have the same problem on a fresh install of CentOS 7.

Answer (score 16):

I had this issue on Dedicated CentOS 7 server, and came across the fix described in this bug report:
[bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=7395](http://web.archive.org/save/bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=7395)

That was a fine solution on the Dedicated to add `gid=5` to devpts in fstab. `screen` now works as expected for all users.

However, I ran across this thread as I was trying to solve the issue on an OpenVZ container of CentOS 7. As there isn't a way to edit the fstab for the server (as far as I could find), I found the following work-around fixed it.

I figured I would drop back by this way and see if it might help anyone else out. 
*(Albeit isn't a very pretty way of doing it.)*

In terminal:

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/screen
chmod 755 /var/run/screen
```

Comment: This answer solved the issue for me, Ubuntu 18.04 running on openvz container

Comment: As the mentioned link doesn't work anymore (neither the one in the Wayback machine or the original one), I'm afraid I don't fully understand the answer. However, I made the `chmod` permission changes, added my user to the `screen` group, and it works again.

Comment: FYI: The solution at the link was to add the parameter `gid=5` into the `devpts` line in the server's `/etc/fstab`.
OpenVZ containers don't allow you to make this modification, so I was prefacing my answer with that information to help make the distinction in solutions.

Answer (score 5):

**Ensure no other `screen` is using that device**

This can be achieved with [How can I determine what process has a file open in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/97844/how-can-i-determine-what-process-has-a-file-open-in-linux) :

```
sudo lsof /dev/ttyS0
```

And then kill that process if that is the case.

For some reason, under this condition, `sudo screen` can still access the device, but then that connection will miss characters, which are consumed by the other `screen`.

**Ensure the user has read and write permission to the file**

E.g. on Ubuntu you want to add the user to the `dialout` group: https://askubuntu.com/a/133244/52975

Comment: thanks for `lsof`, I didn't know that I already have two `screens` running in the background

Answer (score -3):

It might be an errors in your config file

*~/.screenrc*

Try to check it or create dimmy one.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)